# How to silent/quiet HTTPServer and BasicHTTPRequestHandler's stderr output?

Tags: python, httpserver, basehttpserver

I am writing a simple http server as part of my project. Below is a skeleton of my script:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class MyHanlder(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('<html><body><p>OK</p></body></html>')

httpd = HTTPServer(('', 8001), MyHanlder)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

My question: how do I suppress the stderr log output my script produces every time a client connects to my server?

I have looked at the HTTPServer class up to its parent, but was unable to find any flag or function call to achieve this. I also looked at the BaseHTTPRequestHandler class, but could not find a clue. I am sure there must be a way. If you do, please share with me and others; I appreciate your effort.

Comment: The more time I use Python, the more I realise just how much gibberish is involved. Take this:
```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class MyHanlder(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
```

Answer (score 155, accepted):

This will probably do it:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('<html><body><p>OK</p></body></html>')
    def log_message(self, format, *args):
        return

httpd = HTTPServer(('', 8001), MyHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: This gave me such a headache because my httpserver wasn't returning anything when I ran it in the background without a tty. You are a life saver. Thanks!

Comment: @agressen, same frustration here -- and same thanks to MattH.  My app is implemented as a `.pyw` because it's a Tkinter interface, so not having a console window was preventing any replies from being sent.

Comment: you probably want to override `log_request` instead of `log_message`, since the latter is used for other types of logging including errros.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, which leads me to this [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.log_message)

Comment: Note that if you still want to see errors (which you usually do), you can instead override the `log_request` function instead, as `def log_request(self, code='-', size='-'): return`.

Comment: took me a while to notice the difference

Answer (score 1):

To silent/quiet HTTP Server and Basic HTTPRequestHandler stderr output, you can subclass SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler and override the log_message method. Here is the method you will be overriding, sans docstring:

```
def log_message(self, format, *args):
    sys.stderr.write("%s - - [%s] %s\n" % (
        self.address_string(), 
        self.log_date_time_string(),
        format%args)
    )
```

Comment: This explains @matth's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3389505/468252 and extends it (to show what the original code does, which might be useful).

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be late but you can also try changing/setting `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`

```py
import io

stream = io.StringIO()
if (sys.stdout is None) or (sys.stderr is None):
    sys.stdout, sys.stderr = stream, stream
```

It worked for me.