# How to quiet SimpleHTTPServer?

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

I have the following simple Threaded fileserver to be used by my application:

```
class FileServer(Thread):
    """Simple file server exposing the current directory for the thumbnail
    creator
    """

    def __init__(self, port):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.port = port

        Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
        self.httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", port), Handler)

    def run(self):
        self.httpd.serve_forever()

    def stop(self):
        self.httpd.shutdown()
```

How can I prevent SimpleHTTPServer to output "GET 'http:// BLA BLA BLA" at every request? Thanks

Comment: Kind of duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3389305/267781

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can subclass `SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` and override the `log_message` method. Here is the method you will be overriding, sans docstring:

```
def log_message(self, format, *args):
    sys.stderr.write("%s - - [%s] %s\n" %
                     (self.address_string(),
                      self.log_date_time_string(),
                      format%args))
```

So to simply ignore all messages, replace the body of the function with `pass`. For more fine-grained control (i.e if you still want error messages printed), you may instead override the `log_request` and/or `log_error` methods. Original methods are like this:

```
def log_request(self, code='-', size='-'):
    self.log_message('"%s" %s %s',
                     self.requestline, str(code), str(size))

def log_error(self, format, *args):
    self.log_message(format, *args)
```

From 2.7 to 3.1 the module names change, but these methods are unchanged.

Answer (score 14):

Run it this way in Bash:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer &>/dev/null
```

Comment: Awesome, now I have this in my `~/.profile`: `alias server="(python -m SimpleHTTPServer > /dev/null 2>&1 &) && echo 'Server running at 0.0.0.0:80' && open http://0.0.0.0:8000"`

Answer (score 4):

#### There is no need to subclass.

Easier solution:

```
http_handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
http_handler.log_message = lambda a, b, c, d, e: None
```

Or even a safer way, capture all positional and defaulta arguments

```
http_handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
http_handler.log_message = lambda *args, **kwargs: None
```

Or even better, as here is clear that we want to ignore the arguments

```
http_handler.log_message = lambda *_, **__: None
```