# How do I avoid the console logging of http.server

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an `http.server` running inside my code to load a local html, but I don't want the server to log on console every time a request is made.

I looked into this post:
[How to silent/quiet HTTPServer and BasicHTTPRequestHandler's stderr output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389305/how-to-silent-quiet-httpserver-and-basichttprequesthandlers-stderr-output)

And tried it out but it returns an error: `missing 3 required positional arguments`

```
class main()
    def openHttpServer(self):
        port = 8000
        Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
        self.httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", port), Handler)
        self.httpd.serve_forever()
```

I expect it to work the same but without the `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` logging in console.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I fixed it by sub classing as suggested in several post

So, if I was using `http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` as `Handler` I now pass it as a subclass here:

`class quietServer(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):`

And just write the function for the `log_message` with `pass` so it doesn't return a log on requests.

```
def log_message(self, format, *args):
        pass
```

So the whole code would be like this:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8080

class quietServer(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def log_message(self, format, *args):
        pass

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), quietServer) as httpd:
    httpd.serve_forever()
```